# Лямбда-выражения и управляемый код

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Имеется класс C++, написанный с применением управляемого кода. И вот нелегкая привела меня вызвать в данном классе в одном из методов любой из `std::algorithm`. Так вот, студия любезно указала, что лямбда - выражения использовать нельзя. Пришлось написать класс, и сделать его функтором. Так вот вопрос - почему запрещены лямбды?

Код:

```
public ref class edit_base
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        std::string line("abcdefg");
        std::string lineNew;
        std::copy_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::back_inserter(lineNew), [](const char& s) {
            if (s > 10 && s < 100)
                return true;
            return false;
        });
    }
 }
```

Пишу через 17 студию. Компилятор: 19.11.25547

> Error: E2093   локальное лямбда-выражение не допускается в функции-члене класса управляемый

Comment: Лямбда выражения не всегда работают "как надо". Однажды мне пришлось написать на Qt5 класс, создающий диалоговое окно с кнопкой "Назад". Действие для кнопки было переброшено как лямбда в параметрах конструктора. При этом класс хранил QDialog как указатель, не наследовал от QDialog. И создавался он через обычное объявление, без указателя в методе другого класса. В итоге после завершения метода диалоговое окно осталось, а вот лямбда перестала работать. Для меня это оказалось не очевидным, возможно Visual Studio именно по этому и не любит лямбды

Comment: А можно пример кода, который не компилируется? У меня с лямбдами никогда не было проблем.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Пока этот вопрос выглядит как предложение отгадать мелодию без нот.

Comment: В дополнение к просьбам привести код, приведите также версию используемого компилятора, и в каких именно выражениях любезничала студия...

Comment: Вопрос отредактирован.

Comment: Ну так может пометите это правильным тэгом языка программирования. При чём здесь [C++]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, это так. Лямбды компилируются как нативный локальный класс/структура, а такого не может быть внутри управляемого класса.

Поэтому придётся вынести нужный метод наружу:

```
ref class edit_base;

void test(edit_base^ self)
{
    // тут можно обращаться к полям класса (если надо, объявите эту функцию friend'ом)
    std::string line("abcdefg");
    std::string lineNew;
    std::copy_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::back_inserter(lineNew), [](const char& s) {
        if (s > 10 && s < 100)
            return true;
        return false;
    });
}

public ref class edit_base
{
public:
    void test() { ::test(this); }
};
```